# How to debug Magento?

Tags: magento

Is there any way to debug Magento. Basically I am looking

1. Checkout which class are loaded
2. Check if controller or block is overridden or not by new one, if it is created.

Krishna

Comment: it's a php app so debugging it with debugger is the same like any other php app/script.

Comment: Vaguely yes, I am precisely looking if any Magento specific exits.

Comment: http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug

Comment: google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+debug+magento&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score -1):

this can help you, also you can see a entry in my blog

```
http://www.elblogdeselo.com/configurar-magento-en-modo-desarrollador
```

But is in spanish.

Note: search in eclipse, get_class() and debug method of varien object are yout best allied. I recomend you study the architecture of Magento, and navegate between the class herency because debug can be a tedious work.

Comment: the ecomdev extension you're referring to is not a debugger, nor finds error in code: it's to run Unit Tests and work in a TDD way.

Comment: The linked blog is in language other than English is used. Not really helpful!